# Core Data manual migration issue (properties mismatch)

Tags: core-data, migration

I have tried Core Data manual migration today, but I got a problem, many columns in Book entity are moved forward one column.

Here is my mapping model:
[image: mapping model]

and the data after migration:
[image: migrated data]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! Because the sqlite journal_model is WAL, and I was only moving the sqlite file.

Comment: Hello, would you please elaborate? I am having the same issue, but I am still clueless. How can I change the model?

Comment: There are three files in your database directory: xxx.sqlite, xxx.sqlite-shm and xxx.sqlite-wal, you should also move xxx.sqlite-shm and xxx.sqlite-wal